# Failed payment in Stripe Checkout for Subscription - Should i Save checkout session link or should Customer create new Subscription on new attempt

Tags: next.js, stripe-payments, next.js13, checkout, subscription

So implemented everything from webhook, to create portal session, to create checkout session and everything works so far. I am questioning the following. For the subscription.created event with payment method Card with 3ds secure the initial status is incomplete. Only when he retries with another card successfully i am saving the subscription id to the User database document. Is this okay? Because the User can retry paying the subscription with status incomplete for 23 hours right?
But its some extra work i dont want to do if i dont need to.

Say i have to do id, what would i need to save to the user database document to make the user be able to retry a payment even after he exits the checkout website?
To make the user not able to access this checkout revival link after the 23 hours i just have to check the subscription status with incomplete because now it would have become incomplete_expired correct?

**Nevertheless do i need to do it this way?**

Problem descibed above

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Customer portal](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=stripe-hosted) in order to let your customer complete their payments, manage their existing Subscriptions, Invoices and payment methods. In your scenario, you can give your customer the option to open a Stripe [Customer portal](https://stripe.com/docs/customer-management) and complete the purchase their.